# Solution to this signal even or odd

Tags: signal

Can you please explain this function whether it is odd or even step by step:

\$x(t) = cos(t) + sin(t) cos^2(t)\$

Comment: @Nick - totally agree, more a maths question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This function is neither even nor odd:

$$x(-t)=\cos(-t)+\sin(-t)\cos^2(-t)=\cos(t)-\sin(t)\cos^2(t)$$

And since

$$x(-t)\neq x(t)\quad\text{and}\quad x(-t)\neq -x(t)$$

this function is neither even nor odd.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously a homework question so this is more a hint than a full answer.

An even function is a function where \$f(t) = f(-t)\$ for all values of \$t\$

An odd function is a function where \$-f(t) = f(-t)\$ for all values of \$t\$

It is also possible to have a function that is neither odd nor even

Take any value for \$t\$ (\$\frac{\pi}{2}\$ and \$-\frac{\pi}{2}\$ make it easy) and evaluate the function \$x(t)\$ at that value and apply the rules above.

Comment: +1 for proving the method and NOT the answer.